# Integrating HashTag with Chatter component in VisualForce Page

Tags: chatter, visualforce-component, visualforce

We are working with hash tag and chatter and what I am supposed to bring the output was with SalesForce headers. Now we have to integrate the hash tag with chatter in VisualForce Page. Does anyone know is this possible?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you asking how to add a hashtag to a chatter FeedItem using Visualforce? Are you interested in adding a Topic as well or just a hashtag?

Comment: Also, can you post your Visualforce page and controller so we can get a better idea as to what you are trying to accomplish?